# App crashing on iOS 4.2.1 3G iPhone with Base SDK = 4.3 and iOS Deployment Target = 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I have an iOS app that is crashing on my iOS 4.2.1 iPhone 3G test device.  My build is set to a Base SDK of 4.3 and an iOS Deployment Target of 4.0.  When I inspect the device log I see this:

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00c22e00
Crashed Thread:  0

I understand that this means that the code is probably calling a 4.3 API method.  *How do I determine where this is happening?*

Interestingly, when I connect the device to Xcode 4 and deploy as a development device, Xcode 4 says "4.2.1 overriding Base SDK to 4.3" in the scheme drop down.  When connected as a development device in this way, the 4.2.1 iPhone 3G test device runs the app fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Turns out that my app was not crashing on a API method call.  It was crashing because of a Core Data memory issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my app was not crashing on a API method call. It was crashing because of a Core Data memory issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After hard debugging i found the program actually refers to a nonexistent memory (crash was in the callback of NSURLConnection)

So i decided it's a bug in 4.3 or Apple wants to bury 3G devices..whatever

I had installed XCode 3.2.1 with iOS 4.1 SDK. Rebuilt. And my app works.

Answer (score 0):

Change XCode Base SDK to 4.2.1 and see where it doesn't compile - the 4.3 call you're making should be marked as an error.